# Excel treats same date formats differently in formula?

Tags: excel, date, format, formula

I would like to check in a column if date 'A' is smaller(earlier) than date 'B'
The dates are coming from SAP database HANA. I only receive incorrect FALSE message in the logic I'm checking in some cases, but there is no visible difference between the cells and date formats.

date 'A' : 11/23/2020
date 'B' : 11/3/2020

formula : =date 'B' < date 'A'

For the above mentioned dates the formula gives me FALSE by default, while it's true. If I rewrite the date in the cell EXACTLY the same way, it gives TRUE.

(a ' mark might disappear, but I have correct logic feedback with or without this ' mark in front of the date)

Anyone might have any idea?

Comment: one or both of the dates are text that look like dates.  True dates to Excel are numbers that are formatted to look like dates.  You can test by using: `ISNUMBER(A1)` to see if it is a number or text.

Comment: thanks, but I get FALSE on ISNUMBER on both cases, even where the formula works properly

Comment: That formula could work in some cases because it can deal with text values. Those dates are probably both saved as text.

Comment: Then they are text and it is trying to order them alphabetically and not numerically.  Alphabetically `11/2...` comes before `11/3....`.  A number will always come before a string.

Comment: In all cases the dates are text values, I checked where formula works and also where formula doesnt work. Checked with ISTEXT(A1) as well. Currently my only solution is to multiply all dates by 1, so pushing all of them to number formats.

Comment: thanks Scott, yes it makes sense, it's an alphabetical check, I have to convert them to numbers